# What is the correct stripe event when an invoice for a subscription fails?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription whose `collection_method` has been set to `send_invoice`.
I can't figure out the correct webhook event when the invoice for the subscription is sent to the customer each month but the **customer didn't pay it** or the **payment made by the customer failed**.

I think it is `invoice.payment_failed` but I am not sure whether that applies when the **customer doesn't pay the invoice** situation too.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

The `invoice.payment_failed` is the right one to indicate a payment failure, but the case of customer not paying the invoice is a bit different. It depends on your [settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic) to handle the invoice and/or subscription after payment failures or time past due.

If you choose to have the invoices [marked uncollectible](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview#uncollectible), you get the `invoice.marked_uncollectible` event. If there is a related subscription and you chose to modify it, you'd receive a `customer.subscription.updated` event ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.updated)) with the new `status`.

Comment: In the stripe settings the option I see is:
If invoice is overdue by `60` days then mark the invoice as uncollectible.
But I want to change that `60` days limit to `2` days. How can I do that?

Comment: Is `charge.expired` applicable as well?

Comment: You can't set that to 2 days, that's not one of the supported values for the setting. The `charge.expired` event in unrelated to this, it related to uncaptured charges when using separate auth & capture. https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.expired